# Prevent child click event from firing parent's double click event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

[Here is a JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/C6gh7/1/) of what I'm experiencing.

Ideally, the double click event should Not fire if the button is clicked, regardless of the speed or frequency of clicks.

I've tried messing with stopping propagation I can't seem to get anything to work.

The following code:

```
 if(event.target == this)
```

DOES work on JSFiddle, however because I am trying to use this code inside of a custom [widget](http://jqueryui.com/widget/) the `this` keyword does NOT refer to the item being clicked but rather the widget itself.

How can I stop the click-event from firing the parental double-click-event?

**EDIT**

[The solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16326089/573634) was given by [jo8691](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616443/j08691). My problem was that I was stopping the propagation for the click event, not the double-click event. I learned something new! (Stopping click events doesn't not stop double click events, they are more separate than they seem).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/C6gh7/4/ - .stopPropagation() seems to work

Comment: @ZoltanToth -- Not if I click super fast :)

Comment: Zoltan, this does not work. You put `.stopPropagation` on the wrong listener. jo8691 has the right answer. Thanks though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add:

```
$('button').on("dblclick", function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/C6gh7/5/)**